# rmarkdown not rendering some plots when inside a tmux session

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I think this could be R options fix. I have some code like

````
```{r cache=FALSE,fig.cap="Fig 1c. Day of Week Effect on Ratio for    India",fig.width=9,figh.height=6, fig.align='center'}
   f=dau[geo=="IN" & date<"2017-01-01", ]
  invisible(monthplot(ts(f$r,frequency=7,start=c(26,5)),labels=c("m","t","w","th","fr","sa","su"),ylab='ratio' ))
```
````

However, the output html does not have the plot displayed. 
1. This session is running inside a tmux session running on a remote server (headless) (in this case, the plot goes directly to a PDF file Rplots.pdf)
2. If run in an interactive terminal from my laptop, the plot displays.

I think the fix is easy, but not sure what the option would be.

Comment: Any solution for that (there is a similar problem with headless builds using r-hub.io: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48257303/4468078)